# How to find the limit of this sequence?

Tags: limits

How to find the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to + \infty}{S_n}$ where
$$S_n= \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2\cdot 4} + \dfrac{1}{2\cdot 4 \cdot 6} +  \dfrac{1}{2\cdot 4 \cdot 6\cdots 2n}? $$
I know that $\dfrac{1}{2}<S_n<1. $
With Maple, I guess the answer $.6487212707$, but I can not explain.

Comment: You can get a hint from Maple:

> identify(.6487212707);

$$-1 + {\rm e}^{1/2}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$t_r=\frac1{2.4.6.2r}=\frac1 {r!}\left(\frac12\right)^r$$

$$S_n=\sum_{r=1}^nt_r=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1 {r!}\left(\frac12\right)^r$$

So, $\lim_{n\to \infty}S_n=\sum_{r=1}^ \infty\frac1 {r!}(\frac12)^r=\sum_{r=0}^ \infty\frac1 {r!}(\frac12)^r-1=\text{e}^{\frac12}-1$

Google says, $$\sqrt{\text{e}}=1.6487212707$$